# Using paste0 with pipes (%>%) in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I would like to construct a vector of strings from the iris dataset in a following way:
c("speciesvalue1 Sepal.lengthvalue1", "speciesvalue2 Sepal.lengthvalue2","speciesvalue3 Sepal.lengthvalue3"...etc.)

...and additionally I would like to include only the observations having Sepal.Width greater than 3 (i.e. Sepal.Width > 3).

One would think that this is an easy task with pipes:

```
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% paste0(.$Species," ",.$Sepal.Length)
```

However, the second pipe understands the dots, but also thinks that it is supposed to pass the whole data frame to paste0 as its first argument, and I get something like this:

```
[1] "c(5.1, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 5, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 5.1, 5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 6.3, 6.7, 5.9, 6, 6.7, 6.3, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 7.7, 6.9, 6.7, 7.2, 7.9, 6.3, 6.4, 6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.2)setosa 5.1"                    
[2] "c(3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.4, 3.5, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.1, 3.3, 3.6, 3.2, 3.2, 3.8, 3.2, 3.3, 3.2, 3.8, 3.4, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4)setosa 4.7"    
[3] "c(1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4.7, 4.4, 4.8, 4.5, 4.7, 6, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 6.7, 5.7, 5.7, 6, 6.4, 5.6, 5.5, 5.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.4)setosa 4.6"        
[4] "c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.8, 1.6, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.3, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1, 1.8, 2, 2.4, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3)setosa 5"
...
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap the `paste0` in curly brackets to avoid the data frame being passed as the first argument:

```r
iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% 
  {paste0(.$Species," ",.$Sepal.Length)}
#>  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
#>  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
#>  [9] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.8"     "setosa 5.7"    
#> [13] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.7"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [17] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [21] "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.2"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [25] "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [29] "setosa 5.5"     "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.5"    
#> [33] "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.4"    
#> [37] "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"    
#> [41] "setosa 5.3"     "setosa 5"       "versicolor 7"   "versicolor 6.4"
#> [45] "versicolor 6.9" "versicolor 6.3" "versicolor 6.7" "versicolor 5.9"
#> [49] "versicolor 6"   "versicolor 6.7" "virginica 6.3"  "virginica 7.2" 
#> [53] "virginica 6.5"  "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 7.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [57] "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 7.2"  "virginica 7.9"  "virginica 6.3" 
#> [61] "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 6.9"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [65] "virginica 6.8"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.2"
```

But I would probably create the desired output as a column using `mutate` and `pluck` it out of the dataframe at the end of the pipe - this is a more "tidyverse" way of doing things

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% 
  mutate(output = paste0(Species," ", Sepal.Length)) %>%
  pluck('output')
#>  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
#>  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
#>  [9] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.8"     "setosa 5.7"    
#> [13] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.7"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [17] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [21] "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.2"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [25] "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [29] "setosa 5.5"     "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.5"    
#> [33] "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.4"    
#> [37] "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"    
#> [41] "setosa 5.3"     "setosa 5"       "versicolor 7"   "versicolor 6.4"
#> [45] "versicolor 6.9" "versicolor 6.3" "versicolor 6.7" "versicolor 5.9"
#> [49] "versicolor 6"   "versicolor 6.7" "virginica 6.3"  "virginica 7.2" 
#> [53] "virginica 6.5"  "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 7.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [57] "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 7.2"  "virginica 7.9"  "virginica 6.3" 
#> [61] "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 6.9"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [65] "virginica 6.8"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.2"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

If you're familiar with `glue` sintax

```r
iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% 
  glue::glue_data("{Species} {Sepal.Length}")
```

Answer (score 5):

And yet another option would be to use the `magrittr`  exposition pipe `%$%`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(magrittr)

iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %$% 
  paste(Species, Sepal.Length)
#>  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
#>  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
#>  [9] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.8"     "setosa 5.7"    
#> [13] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.7"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [17] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5.1"    
#> [21] "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.2"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [25] "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.8"     "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 5.2"    
#> [29] "setosa 5.5"     "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.5"    
#> [33] "setosa 4.9"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.4"    
#> [37] "setosa 5"       "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.6"    
#> [41] "setosa 5.3"     "setosa 5"       "versicolor 7"   "versicolor 6.4"
#> [45] "versicolor 6.9" "versicolor 6.3" "versicolor 6.7" "versicolor 5.9"
#> [49] "versicolor 6"   "versicolor 6.7" "virginica 6.3"  "virginica 7.2" 
#> [53] "virginica 6.5"  "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 7.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [57] "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 7.2"  "virginica 7.9"  "virginica 6.3" 
#> [61] "virginica 6.4"  "virginica 6.9"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.9" 
#> [65] "virginica 6.8"  "virginica 6.7"  "virginica 6.2"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `with`.  The code below uses no additional packages other than what you are already using and it works with the base R pipe too.  Also use `paste` rather than `paste0`.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% 
  with(paste(Species, Sepal.Length))
##  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
##  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
## ...snip...

iris |>
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) |>
  with(paste(Species, Sepal.Length))
##  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
##  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
## ...snip...
```

We could easily convert the last example to pure base R by replacing `filter` with `subset`.

```
iris |>
  subset(Sepal.Width > 3) |>
  with(paste(Species, Sepal.Length))
##  [1] "setosa 5.1"     "setosa 4.7"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"      
##  [5] "setosa 5.4"     "setosa 4.6"     "setosa 5"       "setosa 4.9"    
## ...snip...
```